# Can't delete item after being added due to tracking issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am adding an entity using the Upsert method below and deleting it after using the Delete method.

However this throws on the `this.Items.Remove(item)` line with the below error.

```
public async Task<TEntity> Upsert(TEntity item)
{
   var entity = this.Context.Update(item);
   await this.SaveChangesAsync();
   return entity.Entity;
}

public async Task Delete(TEntity item)
{
   this.Items.Remove(item);
   await this.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Error:

> The instance of entity type 'x' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 204}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I think the issue here is that, when I add an entity, it is added as tracked and when I try to delete, it can't be deleted while being tracked?

Any help vastly appreciated, I'm still new to Entity Framework.

Comment: I am guessing you are doing both operations on the same transaction(same thread). If it is the case, what you can do remove `SaveChangesAsync()` method from both `Upsert` and `Delete` methods, and add it as a separate method. Then you can do what you want to do in this order: 
`await Upsert(); 
await Delete(); 
await SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: Also, have a look **Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns** from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `Edit` or `Remove` an record form `DataBase`, the `ChaneTracker` change the state of entity to `Modified` or `Removed` **In Current Context**, And if you read the data from the database (**In Current Context**), because the entities are tracked by `ChangeTracker` an error occurs because in the `ChangeTracker` can't exist two record with a key at the same time.
so you must clear tracked entities from `ChangeTracker`.

Add this code after `await this.SaveChangesAsync();` to detach records from `ChangeTracker`

```cs
foreach (var entity in this.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
     entity.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Comment: that worked, thanks! i previously tried this, but before the `SaveChangesAsync()`!

Comment: @mb1231 Good luck :)

Comment: I hope everything is ok in Tehran. Stay safe :)

Comment: @mb1231 Also for London and the whole world